# Arrange by custom order in dplyr using dynamic column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to arrange a tibble based on a certain column (but setting the column based on a name dynamically set by a variable).

Below is the code I currently am trying but am getting an error. The second paste of code works (where I have hard coded in the column name of symbol which I want to be set based off of a variable instead).

```
library(tidyverse)

group_var <- "symbol"

date_seq <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2009-12-31"), by = "days")
test_tbl <- tibble::tibble("date" = rep(date_seq, 3),
                           "symbol" = rep(c("test3", "test1", "test2"), each = length(date_seq)),
                           "value" = c(rnorm(length(date_seq), sd = 0.05),
                                       rnorm(length(date_seq), sd = 0.05),
                                       rnorm(length(date_seq), sd = 0.05)))

order_var <- c("test1", "test2", "test3")
test_tbl_final <- test_tbl %>%
  dplyr::arrange(factor(!!group_var, levels = order_var), date)
```

Below is the code that works and shows what I am trying to accomplish:

```
library(tidyverse)

date_seq <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2009-12-31"), by = "days")
test_tbl <- tibble::tibble("date" = rep(date_seq, 3),
                           "symbol" = rep(c("test3", "test1", "test2"), each = length(date_seq)),
                           "value" = c(rnorm(length(date_seq), sd = 0.05),
                                       rnorm(length(date_seq), sd = 0.05),
                                       rnorm(length(date_seq), sd = 0.05)))

order_var <- c("test1", "test2", "test3")
test_tbl_final <- test_tbl %>%
  dplyr::arrange(factor(symbol, levels = order_var), date)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use `as.symbol` from base R

```
test_tbl_final <- test_tbl %>%
  dplyr::arrange(factor(!!as.symbol(group_var), levels = order_var), date)
```

Comment: Thank you, love the base R function mention.

Answer (score 3):

You need `rlang:sym` to convert `group_var` from character `symbol` to a symbol `symbol` and then use `!!` to evaluate the symbol as a column object:

```
test_tbl %>% 
    arrange(factor(!!rlang::sym(group_var), levels = order_var), date)

# A tibble: 10,959 x 3
#         date symbol         value
#       <date>  <chr>         <dbl>
# 1 2000-01-01  test1  0.0519143671
# 2 2000-01-02  test1 -0.0464782439
# 3 2000-01-03  test1 -0.0295441613
# ...
```