# How to sort a dataframe by variable number of column?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I want to sort a data frame by a variable number of columns.  For example, with the data frame below, I would like to sort by column "x" then by column "y":

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "D", "A", "C", "D"), y = c(8, 3, 9, 9, 8),
      z = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1))
```

I cannot specify columns like:

```
library(dplyr)
arrange(df,x,y)
```

because my code must be able to order data frame by a variable number of columns (for this data frame: 1, 2 or 3 columns).

I tried the following:

```
columnsOrder = c("x","y")
arrange(df,columnsOrder)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Or maybe `arrange(df, !!as.symbol(columnsOrder))`, not sure how it works just copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015759/arrange-by-custom-order-in-dplyr-using-dynamic-column-names

Comment: Question: Are you limited for some reason to _only_ using the `arrange` function to sort your data frame?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen from what I understand, OP wants to use a `vector` containing variables to be used for the sorting without having to specify the variables directly in the call to `arrange`, so question a bit more specific than just order/sort, but maybe the answer is still somewhere in the Q&A

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah `arrange(df, !!as.symbol(columnsOrder))` works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not limited to `arrange` function but I got issue to install `Deducer` library in order to use `sortData`.

Comment: @Cath You perfectly understand the problem. Thanks, your solution is more elegant or simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "reach" the real columns, you can either use function `arrange_` (which is deprecated now...) instead of `arrange`, with parameter `.dots` to pass your vector of variable names:

```
arrange_(df, .dots=columnsOrder)
#  x y z
#1 A 8 1
#2 A 9 1
#3 C 9 2
#4 D 3 1
#5 D 8 1
```

Or you can do it with `rlang::syms` and `quasiquotation` to create names from your strings vector:

```
df %>% arrange(!!! rlang::syms(columnsOrder))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tested it with another data frame:
`df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "D", "A", "C", "D"), y = c(8, 8, 9, 9, 3),  z = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1))` 
 and it was just sorted by first column.

Comment: Hi @Chris, indeed `get` wasn't going past the first variable, I edited my answer, it should work now